# Is there any way to check whether a code change altered the binary?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, il

I presume that if the C# code is unchanged, the generated IL will be the same each build. The problem is that 2 EXE files generated from the same code don't have the same hash.

I would like to check whether a change in code style generates a different IL. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Every time you build a different binary will be produced, even if the code is identical (a build produces a GUID embedded in the assembly, which will be different on each compilation).

Comment: We may be able to help if you explain **why** you want a change in code style to generate different IL.

Comment: @DourHighArch I don't, I want to assure myself that nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools you can use to disassemble the EXE and compare their content. Look at this blog http://immitev.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/ways-to-compare-net-assemblies.html

[]'s

Comment: By the way, there's a feature suggestion at Telerik's JustDecompile (another disassembler) site that fits your needs. I voted on this, let's help it gain attention from its developers:  http://justdecompile.uservoice.com/forums/113277-justdecompile-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2664373-enable-a-feature-to-compare-versions-of-an-assembl

Answer (score 4):

You are making a bad assumption. A rebuild without code change will deliver a different binary.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927785/426894

> Every time you run the compiler you should get a different output.

And

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results.aspx

> **Is compiling the same C# program twice guaranteed to produce the same
>   binary output?**
>
> No.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), an open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler.

[image]