# Can I force a build to produce identical file hashes on different computers?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently in the process of writing an auto-updater/patcher for my application.

The issue I'm having is that even though the Project files and Solutions are identical on my computer and the build server, the resulting binaries are producing different hashes. This makes it much more difficult for me to test, and since my application is supposed to supplement the development process I need to ensure that the files are identical.

The image below shows the differences between the build server's dll and mine.

[image: File difference between build server and mine]

Is there any way around this?

Alternatively, I could somehow store the repository revision number during the build process but that produces it's own set of issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the binary output not equal when compiling again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927558/why-is-the-binary-output-not-equal-when-compiling-again)

Comment: Interesting, however I feel like the reasoning the top commentor gives there is wrong. The C# compiler does NOT embed a freshly generated GUID on every compilation. I tested this by cleaning and rebuilding the project several times, each time I got an identical hash.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can never rely on the C# compiler to provide binary equivalence. Any instance where the results are equivalent is merely a coincidence.

Comment: I agree, that is not something I would rely a test on.

Comment: But why must they have the same hash? Hashing seems to be the wrong solution to the problem.