# The data within compiled dlls is different on each build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, build

the dlls generated by compiled projects seem to contain mismatched data on each build. Nothing has changed within the project, but when i look inside the dlls (using ildasm for decompiling)  the dlls are different.

they contain the same data, however it is in the wrong order

first build

[image: before]

second build

[image: after]

(notice the line numbers)

is there a project setting that can prevent this from happening? i've no idea why the code is in the wrong order.

Any help is much appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

> the code is in the wrong order

Once compiled, there isn't code anymore but *bytecode*.

And you **can't expect same binaries** between two compilations. See [Why is the binary output not equal when compiling again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927558/why-is-the-binary-output-not-equal-when-compiling-again)

Comment: I see your point. How are developers supposed to know if a DLL has changed then? I'm basically in a situation where i'm trying to build a release (patch folder) which contains dlls that have changed. Due to this problem, all of the dlls are included in the patch (making it huge).