# .NET - why do assembly contents change with the same code?

Tags: .net

I have a solution with multiple layers of project dependencies, and at the lowest level there are some utility libraries. I frequently change them because I need to make minor corrections to the implementation without affecting the signature of any of the exposed objects (e.g. bug fixes).

When I build the solution after making those changes, the contents of all the DLL files that reference these utility libraries change downstream. For example, library A needs a bug fix without any signature changes. Library B references A, and library C references B. After build, both B and C are modified.

I find that illogical. Why would dependent libraries change due to an upstream dependency's internal code change?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927558/why-is-the-binary-output-not-equal-when-compiling-again

Comment: The file header of an executable file includes the time it was created.  This of course doesn't have anything to do with signature changes, the CLR is very good at catching a mistake.

Comment: In principle this could be done. It's just not implemented in MSBuild. "Resharper build" does it. It monitors API surface changes and seems to be capable to skip unnecessary builds. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/10/15/introducing-resharper-build/

Comment: @MichaelLiu thanks.

Comment: @usr thanks for the Resharper suggestion. Last time I tried using it, VS became slow and unstable and didn't provide enough benefits to justify the cost (even ignoring Resharper's actual price for a moment). I'm pretty sure it will be a similar deal here; one useful feature (for me, at least) and a whole bunch of useless ones that carry a ton of weight.

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15167409-only-build-if-referenced-libraries-signatures-chan